# Why I get Null value from view to controller only for one column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-upload, image-upload

I am practice CRUD operation in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I try to upload single image method. The image is upload on create method. But when I try to use edit method without change in image. It give null value on Edit post method.

I make image column as string and save only the random name generated by AJAX url via javascript. On time on Create, Image upload + javascript run and get random name + save in database. But when I try to edit method, without upload new image it save as Null (the image show on edit page.)

Code for controller `Edit` post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, CustomerMaster customerMaster, IFormCollection formData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_context.CustomerMasters.Any(x => x.MobileNo == customerMaster.MobileNo && x.CustomerId != id))
            {
                CustomerMaster customer = await _context.CustomerMasters.FindAsync(id);
                customer.CustomerName = customerMaster.CustomerName;
                customer.MobileNo = customerMaster.MobileNo;
                customer.Email = customerMaster.Email;
                customer.Address = customerMaster.Address;
                customer.Image = customerMaster.Image;
                customer.WhenEntered = DateTime.UtcNow;

                _context.Update(customer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name with same mobile no. already exists.");
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(customerMaster);
}
```

Here is my `edit.cshtml` :

''''

```
@model Customer_Crud_Demo.Models.CustomerMaster

@using Customer_Crud_Demo.Common

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    string imagePath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Image) ? "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" : Config.customerImagePath + Model.Image.Replace(".", ".");
}
```

In config

```
customerImagePath = "/Content/MultiCustomerImg/"
```

edit.cshtml inside form

```
<form asp-action="Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="CustomerId" />
        <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" asp-for="Image" id="fuCustomerImage" class="fu form-control" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" />
                </td>
                <td>
  <input type="button" value="Upload" id="btnUploadImage" class="btn btn-primary" data-URL="CustomerMaster/UploadFile" data-path="/Content/CustomerImages" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="error" colspan="2">
                    Please upload image of 200 X 200 and size less than 150KB.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
                        
        <div class="singleImage">
            <img src="@imagePath" alt="Alternate Text" id="ImgUploadedImage" height="200" width="200" />
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Image, new { id = "image" })
        </div>
</form>
```

What is my mistake? Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Edit.cshtml`, You have two `input` tag with same Name:

**1.**

```
<input type="file" asp-for="Image" id="fuCustomerImage" class="fu form-control" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" />
```

**2.**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Image, new { id = "image" })
```

They will all generate code like `<input  Name="Image" ..../>` in HTML.

`ModelBinding` will just bind the value of the first `Input`, This is why you will get null even you don't change any in Image. You can refer to this code:

**Edit.cshtml**

```
<input type="file" Name="file" id="fuCustomerImage" class="fu form-control" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" />
```

**Edit Method**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, CustomerMaster customerMaster, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_context.CustomerMasters.Any(x => x.MobileNo == customerMaster.MobileNo && x.CustomerId != id))
                {
                    CustomerMaster customer = await _context.CustomerMasters.FindAsync(id);
                        customer.CustomerName = customerMaster.CustomerName;
                        customer.MobileNo = customerMaster.MobileNo;
                        customer.Email = customerMaster.Email;
                        customer.Address = customerMaster.Address;

                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        //I don't how you save file as string in database, Here i just save file name as an example
                        customer.Image = file.FileName
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        customer.Image = customerMaster.Image;
                    }
                        
                        customer.WhenEntered = DateTime.UtcNow;

                        _context.Update(customer);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name with same mobile no. already exists.");
                }
            }


        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(customerMaster);
    }
```